# does this wifi card fit any of these pci slots?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express

Here's an image of my motherboard (from a dell optiplex 740):

[image]
[image: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/593/2cak.jpg]

Will any of these two intel centrino cards fit in here?

- INTEL CENTRINO ADVANCED-N 6235
  (=Mini PCIexpress)

[image]

- Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 for Desktop IEEE
  (=PCI Express x1)

[image]

Comment: Check the specifications for your computer.  The number of PCI-E slots your computer has is listed there.  I can tell you that your motherboard does not support the `Mini PCIexpress` standard.

Comment: @Ramhound it mentions a PCI Express x16: 80 Gbps. But isn't that one the one the left of the two grey ones, in use by a card?

Comment: You are indeed correct your only `PCI Express x16` slot is being used by a card.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 for Desktop IEEE (=PCI Express x1), then yes. It can be installed in the Pci-e x16 slot that you have on the motherboard.

You have a Pci-e slot, it is just being used (By graphics card?). As the motherboard has a VGA port, you could use the on board graphics, and swap the card with the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 for Desktop IEEE (=PCI Express x1).

For the INTEL CENTRINO ADVANCED-N 6235 (=Mini PCIexpress), yes, but with a separate adaptor such as this example,

[image: mini pcie]

you could use the mini Pci e express. After looking at various models the price range is $10 to $21 US(and up).

Comment: You could, in theory use a mini pcie card with a simple adaptor. You arn't entirely incorrect but if you already have a spare mini pcie card, its worth considering.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - well what do you know about that, you are right, there are adaptors. I will edit. Thanks for the good point.

Answer (score 2):

Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6205 for Desktop one should fit as your mo-bo should have a PCI-EX x1, but you can't really see it on photo. (***Incorrect***)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added a full picture of the same motherboard found on the web.

Comment: Although almost all photos on Google for your motherboard do have a PCI-ex x1, having a look at your photo it seems your mobo doesn't have one. So you can't really use them. I guess the mobo has a few versions out there

Comment: @Alex - the slot in the photo has a card in it. Pci-e slot is there.

Comment: http://web.amd.com/en-us/partners/dell/docs/opti_740techspecs.pdf the desktop varient has a PCI-e x1 connector, the mini tower varient dosen't. Curious really.

Comment: @Carl B, do you really have to mention it if it's already IN USE? Of course it's there, you won't find a desktop mother without a PCI-ex nowadays :)